# Unable to upgrade to postgresql 13

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, postgresql-11

I'm getting the following error:

> postgres@:~/>cat loadable_libraries.txt could not load library
> "$libdir/plpython2": ERROR:  could not access file
> "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory In database: db_name

When trying to run pg_upgrade from PostgreSQL-11 to PostgreSQL-13.

```
/usr/pgsql-13/bin/pg_upgrade -b /usr/pgsql-11/bin -B /usr/pgsql-13/bin -c -d /localpart0/db/postgres/11/db_name/data -D/localpart0/db/postgres/13/db_name/data -j 20 -r -v --clone
```

I don't have any plpython* extensions and already tried changing the pg_pltemplate entries for plpythonu and plpython2u to plpython3 and run the pg_upgrade but it fails either way.

Installed Packages:

> postgresql11-plpython.x86_64    11.7-1PGDG.rhel7  @postgres11.prd
> postgresql13-plpython3.x86_64   13.1-1PGDG.rhel7  @postgres13.prd

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: "I don't have any plpython* extensions"  What does that mean?  You aren't using them in either system?  The extensions aren't created in either system?  The control files don't even exist in either system?

Comment: I'm using Linux 3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 23 15:46:38 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: The only update I have is that by removing any and all references of plpython2 from the pg11 cluster, I was able to run the upgrade. Not sure if this means that I'm going to have to upgrade any and all plpython2 functions to plpython3 prior to upgrade or not...I thought pg13 upgrade was going going to be compatible with plpython2.

Comment: Relevant announcement from Devrim Gündüz, who builds the RHEL PostgreSQL RPMs: https://people.planetpostgresql.org/devrim/index.php?/archives/106-What-is-new-in-PostgreSQL-13-RPMs.html … short answer, the packager dropped plpython2 support.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has a better answer or suggestion please let me know. Otherwise, I believe I found the answer in the pgsql-general mailing list;

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/936117.1605644139%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Hi,

On Tue, 2020-11-17 at 21:00 +0100, Marcin Giedz wrote:

> Hi all, trying to performe upgrade from 12 to 13 installed from
> Centos8 repo gives such error:
>
> cat loadable_libraries.txt
> could not load library "$libdir/plpython2": ERROR: could not access
> file "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory

I dropped PL/Python support along with PostgreSQL 13 RPMs.

### Regards,

Devrim Gündüz
Open Source Solution Architect, Red Hat Certified Engineer
Twitter: @DevrimGunduz , @DevrimGunduzTR